# Ionic/Angular $urlRouterProvider.otherwise issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am having issues with Ionic/Angular. I am new to ionic, and need some help. Most of the stuff online is for splash screens, so I came here for further assistance.

I want the app to default land on to the "welcome" page. What do I need to write? My code is as follows.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard  
      // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.welcome', {
    url: "/welcome",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/welcome.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.bulletin', {
    url: "/bulletin",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/bulletin.html"
      }
    }
  })
    .state('app.lunch', {
    url: "/lunch",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/lunch.html"
      }
    }
  })
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/welcome");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the }); above the $urlRouterProvider since you have to define the otherwise() inside of the config;

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // if the path doesn't match any of the urls you configured
    // otherwise will take care of routing the user to the specified url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
})
```